# Do we know that $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ is an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $U= \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } z^n=1\}$.

Show that $(U, \cdot)$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{*}=\mathbb{C}-\{ 0\}$

Let $a,b \in U$.

So,$\exists n,m \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } a^n=1, b^m=1$.

We have to check if $a \cdot b' \in U$.

We suppose $k=m \cdot n$

Can I get from the relation $(a \cdot b')^k$ to this : $a^k \cdot (b^{-1})^k$?

Do we know that $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ is an abelian group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The multiplication of $\Bbb C^*$ is the same multiplication of $\Bbb C$ as a field, which is commutative, therefore the group is abelian.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ an abelian group,because:

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}^{*}$,because:

 $$(a \cdot b) \cdot c= a \cdot (b \cdot c)$$

$$1 \in \mathbb{C}^{*} \text{ is the neutral element }$$ 

$$\frac{1}{a} \in \mathbb{C}^{*}$$

$$a \cdot b=b \cdot a$$

???

Comment: The first three really just say it's a group, and the last one says it's an abelian group, yes. However you're not explaining why these things are true, you just state them. The reason $\Bbb C^*$ is an abelian group is because in the axioms of a field we require multiplication to be associative, commutative and every non-zero element has a non-zero multiplicative inverse (and there is a multiplicative neutral element, $1$ which is not $0$, of course).